# What's next after Windows Server 2008 R2?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2

Looking at Windows Server 2008 R2 and wondering about the value of Software Assurance. I must be just fumble fingered today because I can't seem to find a roadmap for where we're going from here.

1. When's the next proposed release date for version next?
2. Where's currently the best place to purchase with or without SA? Been awhile since I've done direct purchasing.

Comment: I'm just happy that the server and client releases are back in lockstep.  For a while there it was seriously schizophrenic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't remember an exact url but if I remember correctly, Micrososft has committed to a 3 year release cycle, with interim (R2) releases after 18 months.

Comment: And in the past they committed to a 2 year cycle, but still took 5 years to release. It comes when it comes.

Comment: Agreed. R2/Win7 was actually somewhat on schedule but time will tell.

Answer (score 0):

The next version Windows Server 8 (my be renamed) out around mid next year.

Comment: This answer would be improved by providing more substance and references to support your information.